# How to pass null filter in elastic search + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I want to filter search result. I want to search that if 'manuf_id' is not specified than is should return all records. below is my search query in elastic.

```
$params = [
            'index' => $this->client->getIndex(),
            'type'  => $this->client->getType(),
            "from" => $from, "size" => $productPerPage,
            'body'  => [
           "query" => [
               "bool" => [
                  "must" => [
                     [
                          "multi_match" => [
                              "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                              "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                              "query" => 'samsung'
                          ]
                     ],
                        //$conditionArr
                     [
                          "term"=> ["manuf_id"=>null]
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
            ],
       ];
```

Above query is not running. is there something I am missing? ANy help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass this condition only in case when it necessary, like this:

```
$params = [
    'index' => $this->client->getIndex(),
    'type'  => $this->client->getType(),
    "from" => $from, "size" => $productPerPage,
    'body'  => [
        "query" => [
           "bool" => [
              "must" => [
                 [
                      "multi_match" => [
                          "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                          "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                          "query" => 'samsung'
                      ]
                 ],
              ]
           ]
        ]
    ],
];
if ($manufId > 0) {
  $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = [
      'term' => ['manuf_id' => $manufId],
  ];
}
```

Comment: that worked like a chram. Do you have any reference How can I add AND condtion.

Comment: Just add one more element into `$params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][]`